# How to connect to Google App Engine server in internal network iMac?

Tags: localhost, google-app-engine, airport, imac

I have 3 iMacs and a Windows machine on my home network, all connected via an Airport Extreme router.  I'm developing Google App Engine applications locally on one of the iMacs, and can view applications using http://localhost:8080 (or whatever port I choose).

How do I connect to those applications from other iMacs and Windows machines in my network?  I've located the IP for the iMac hosting Google App Engine:  10.0.1.7.  But when I try http://10.0.1.7:8080 from another machine it will not load the page.

Comment: Please read our FAQs next time.

Comment: Can you link this to my account?

Answer (score 8):

See docs for the --address option here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver.html

Basically:

1. On the machine running appengine: Open System Preferences > Network and write down the IP (eg. 1.2.3.4)
2. Use this IP with the address option, ie. "--address 1.2.3.4", when you launch the dev appserver.
3. Visit http://1.2.3.4:8080/ from any machine in your local network.

Comment: Sorry I did not see this in time to mark it as the answer. It worked!

Answer (score 6):

For those of you finding this page but are running App Engine 1.7.6 or newer, use

```
--host=0.0.0.0
```

instead of

```
--address 0.0.0.0
```

A big update in the Development Server resulted in a large number of options being changed or removed (all shortened flags were removed), as well as python 2.5 support being killed. On the upside, the admin host/port can also be changed with

```
--admin_host=0.0.0.0 --admin_port=8000
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/old_devserver

Comment: This works for me: "goapp serve --host=192.168.1.15". Then I can use my iPhone to talk with this GAE app in LAN via home wifi, using url like "http://192.168.1.15:8080".

Answer (score 0):

Use the --address option to bind to all addresses:

```
dev_appserver --address 0.0.0.0 my_app
```

This will then work from anywhere.  The default is to bind to a loopback address only (127.0.0.1).