# Accessing localhost on my iPhone

Tags: macos, localhost

I've found similarly titled questions, but none that directly address my issue. I'm running Google App Engine server on my Macbook, and it was configured to use port 8080 on localhost. And so anytime I wanted to run my site, I'd just go to `localhost:8080/saveuser` and everything worked fine.

Now, I want to access this same site on my iPhone. I can't just do localhost on my iPhone, so I set up Web Sharing on my mac, and it's set up to `http://192.168.1.106/~username`. I can access this from my iPhone, but it only displays a directory of my files, and doesn't actually run the Python script. The only way my Python scripts actually run is if I do `localhost:8080` on my computer.

What can I do about this?

Comment: Have you tried `http://192.168.1.106:8080/saveuser`? If so, did you setup your python server to bind to 0.0.0.0 or 192.168.1.106 or something like that?

Comment: Ya tried that, that doesn't work on neither my computer or iPhone. When I access `192.168.1.106/~mohabitar`, it says this on the bottom: `Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.8 with Suhosin-Patch Server at 192.168.1.106 Port 80`

Comment: Not sure what port 80 means..my Google App Engine server is configured on port 8080. If I try to change the configuration to port 80, I get a configuration error

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_%28computer_networking%29

Comment: I know what port 80 means..I just don't know what it means for my problem. My Google App Engine server is configured to port 8080, and if on the bottom it says port 80, that could be the reason it's not working. I just don't know what to make of it

Comment: Web sharing simply means an apache server running on port 80. It has nothing to do with your GAE server since it uses a totally different port. Just visit `http://192.168.1.106:8080` and see what happens. If it doesn't work, you should check the firewall and port binding.

Comment: Try this and see if it solves your problem: http://superuser.com/questions/243757/how-to-connect-to-google-app-engine-server-in-internal-network-imac